# How to restrict special characters in EditText using InputType from activity?

Tags: android

I am trying to restrict special characters as follows:
but its not working properly.

```
 final EditText editText = new EditText(Settings.this);
    LayoutParams editTextLayoutParams 
    = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    editText.setLayoutParams(editTextLayoutParams);
    editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT );//| android.text.InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER );
```

Comment: What is not working? What are you trying to accomplish? What are you seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InputType is used to hint to the IME which mode it should display as (e.g. email address entry, number entry, alphabet entry). Even if the IME mode doesn't provide a means to enter invalid characters, the user can still paste any characters possible into the EditText.

What you need to use is an InputFilter, to sanitize the EditText's value as each character is entered.